# How to build server.js express server around a remote github page JSON object

Tags: node.js, json, github-pages

I have a GitHub page with one file in it: `model.json`. In `model.json` is a JSON object. I'd like to be able to access that object via a fetch request triggered in the frontend of my app.

However, I have only done mock localhost express `server.js`es thus far, and I don't know how to point the `server.js` file at a remote server.

That is, typically what I have done is something like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const CORS = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(CORS());

let modelObj = modelJSON; 
// ^this "modelJSON" would be the json object in question,
// whether accessed remotely or locally.

app.get("/model.json", (req, res) => {
  res.send(modelObj);
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Server listening on port 5000");
});
```

I'm wondering how to make this listen to my `https://<my-github-username>.github.io` page instead of port 5000.

(Incidentally, will I want this server.js file in my local project/app file or in the github page root directory?)